# Custom URL field in Joomla - Remove mailto prefix

Tags: php, url, joomla, field, mailto

in Joomla I use a URL custom field (MAILTO schema) to display an email address.
The problem is that Joomla insert mailto prefix twice in the code: once in href attribute and another one between link tags, like this:

```
<span class="field-value"><a href="mailto:myEmail@some.site" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">mailto:myEmail@some.site</a></span>
```

...and this is php code that manage its display:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$value = $field->value;

if ($value == '')
{
    return;
}

$attributes = '';

if (!JUri::isInternal($value))
{
    $attributes = ' rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"';
}

echo sprintf('<a href="%s"%s>%s</a>',
    htmlspecialchars($value),
    $attributes,
    htmlspecialchars($value)
);
```

I would like to remove mailto prefix between link tags.

How to proceed? … perhaps with a regex rule? Problem, I’m not a developer…

Thank you for your help,

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your Reply,I think you can try again.

My English is a little bad,some places may be Unclear expression.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbJjj.png)

```
echo sprintf('<a href="%s"%s>%s</a>',
preg_replace("/(^(http|https|ftp):\/\/)|(^mailto:)/i","",htmlspecialchars($value)),
$attributes,
htmlspecialchars($value));


// you can test it
$value = "http://www.kinoki.at";
$value = "mailto:info@kinoki.at";
echo "<pre>";
print_r( preg_replace("/(^(http|https|ftp):\/\/)|(^mailto:)/i","",htmlspecialchars($value)));
echo "<pre>";exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it’s too generic. PHP code that I reported above (after your answer) is also valid for the display of other protocols (http:// https:// ftp:// ...) that are used for URL custom fields with the following schemas http:// https:// ftp://

Comment: thank you again for your reply, I’m traveling for the moment, I’ll try it tomorrow evening when I come back to the office ;)

Comment: ...tested your code but mailto prefix is still displayed between link tags :/

Comment: you can add schemas  in php function which is preg_replace.

Comment: Hello again,
I realized that the piece of code works only for http and https schema (not tested for ftp), but not for mailto schema, strange ...
In any case it’s not in the href attribute that mailto prefix must be deleted (your code delete schema in href attribute), but between  [<a>] tags, indeed in my case mailto prefix it's just a simple text ...

[screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAHCu3nfUHxJLrdoCgR8VVMiLwV5D2eRM0U)

Comment: Hello and thank you again for your reply :)
no problem with your englishn, mine is not better
…but what part of code should I take? the first or the second solution? 
Anyway I think that Jan's solution is perhaps the better solution to follow since it is recommended by the Joomla documentation.

Comment: ... and is a Joomla built-in email cloaking function. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You likely run into this issue because Joomla tries to cloak the e-mail address. Best would be to use the recommended way of showing the e-mail address, using the built-in e-mail cloaking functions.

```
echo JHtml::_('email.cloak', $value);
```

See also: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_cloak_email_addresses

Comment: Hello Jan and thank you for your reply, indeed I think that would be the best solution to follow, but since I'm not a developer, perhaps you could tell me how to integrate it into the code I reported at the top of the page?

Comment: Instead of the part `echo sprintf('<a href="%s"%s>%s</a>..... );` put the code I gave. I edited it to use your e-mail address as value.

Comment: You also don't need the lines that reference the `$attributes` variable, as that is only needed to build up a link.

Comment: Hello Jan and thank you for your reply,
I replaced old code by yours, [email address seems to be cloaked](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAEwi5U5S9hLtrY-k52-IxQLA8EwRaLuaK4), but the mailto prefix is still displayed.
In Joomla, [email custom field forces me to insert the mailto schema](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ezmmigh2qtl7sad/email-cloaked.gif), maybe that's the reason why the prefix is always displayed?

Comment: Ah yes that will be your problem, that extension is forcing something the wrong way. Contact the author of the extension for advise.